# Numerical method for calculating large discrete harmonic function

Tags: numerical-methods, harmonic-functions, graph-laplacian

I am working on a problem, and for testing purposes, I want to do the following.
Let be given a sparse graph $G(V,E)$ with edge weight matrix $W$, and $|V|$ large (anywhere from $10^3$ to $10^6$). We are looking for a function $f: V \to \mathbb{R}$, such that
$$f(i)=0, \quad f(j)=1, \quad f(k) -\sum_{l} W_{kl} f(l) = 0 \quad \forall k\neq i,j$$
That is, we are looking for a discrete harmonic function with boundary conditions as above. To my best knowledge there are two approaches when solving problems like this:

1. Solve the linear system arising from the problem using some direct method. This could be done for $|V|$ small, but no chance for large $|V|$s.
2. Iterate over the vertices, and set $f(k)=\sum_{l}W_{kl}f(l)$, i.e. modify the function to be locally harmonic, and repeat until convergence. Again, this method might be feasible for toy problems, but definitely not for many vertices.

I'll also explain what I need this for, maybe that helps. In one interpretation, the problem I am solving is equivalent to applying a voltage of 1 volts to two arbitrary junctions in a massive resistor network, and trying to calculate the voltages at each point of the network.

Comment: You get a sparse linear system that you try to solve via the Jacobi method. Is there any condition that assures diagonal dominance? Or any other condition that ensures the fixed-point iteration as described in 2. is contractive?

Comment: Originally I got 2. from Doyle & Snell Random Walks and Electrical networks (pp. 16-21) where the following sketch is suggested. Let $f$ be the initial guess, and suppose that $f(k) \leq \sum_{l} W_{kl} f(l)$ for every $k \neq i, j$. Then, though iterations this property is preserved, and $f(k)$ is monotone increasing. Thus for every $k$ we have $f(k)$ bounded and monotone increasing. Further, we have a finite set of vertices, so pointwise convergence implies that $f$ is convergent.

Comment: Increasing is easy to see, but why is it bounded? Why does an all-nonnegative solution exist? "It's physical" is a strong reason, but is it stable under pertubations like measurement errors, or small non-linear terms in a "truer" physical model (that the "truer" system has an admissible solution is in general no guarantee that the linear system has an admissible solution)? What are the mathematical limits, what is the theoretical structure?

Comment: Bounded can be reasoned it the following way. If $f$ is not bounded, then exists a minimal time $t$ after which there is $k$ such that $f(k)>1$. Then, since $t$ minimal $k$ was the last updated vertex. But $f(k)$ is currently the average of its neighbouring vertices, but then it has a neighbour $l$ s.t. $f(l)>1$, contradicting the minimality of $t$.

Comment: In terms of the existence of a non-negative solution, note that a solution to the problem is harmonic, hence it takes its maximum and minimum on the boundary (i.e. the points with fixed value). Since we fixed these to $0$ and $1$, any solution must be non-negative. Obviously, one needs to verify the existence of a solution at all, for this to make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that $W$ can be assumed to be row normalised!